# How to Play External Audio Files Violating Content Security Policy Directive in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, audio, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I am developing a Chrome extension that enables users to send selected text to a server, which then converts it into speech and returns an MP3 URL for playback.

However, on certain websites, I encounter a Content Security Policy error, preventing the loading and playback of the MP3 URL. The error message is as follows:

```
Refused to load media from 'https://storage.googleapis.com/***8d7fc.mp3' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'media-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Given this situation, how can I successfully play audio files stored on an external server that violate the Content Security Policy directive?

#### What I have tried:

##### Change content security policy of manifest.json

Pattern 1

```
    "content_security_policy": {
        "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; media-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com;"
    },
```

Pattern 2

```
    "content_security_policy": {
        "content_security_policy": "default-src *; media-src *;"
    },
```

Both pattern I got still same error.

```
Refused to load media from 'https://storage.googleapis.com/9aed6d91.mp3' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'media-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

##### Insert meta tag.

I attempted to overwrite the meta tag, but the error remains unresolved. I presume this is because the header information takes precedence. Here is the meta tag I used:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; img-src *; media-src *; font-src *; style-src *">
```

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

### Note

Up until now, I was able to read external files without any problems. However, recently, I suddenly became unable to read external files. Therefore, it may have something to do with this since it is close to the date and time when the problem occurred.

[Content Security Policy Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#changes-from-level-2)

W3C Working Draft, 20 September 2023

Comment: You can do it inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/), no need to modify CSP.

Answer (score 0):

The header doesn't take precedence, your meta tag adds another policy, and any content needs to pass all policies. You will need to relax the existing policy, and if you can't do that, there is not  much else you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @wOxxOm!

I solved this problem with [offscreen](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/).

This is example. Please add offscreen settings on your `manifest.json`.

```
    "permissions": [
        "offscreen" # add
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
            # add
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "offscreen.js" 
            ]
        }
    ],
```

Create offscreen and Send message (audio url) to offscreen from `background.js`

```
async function createOffscreen() {
    // Create the offscreen document if it doesn't already exist
    if (await chrome.offscreen.hasDocument()) return;
    await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
        url: 'offscreen.html',
        reasons: ['AUDIO_PLAYBACK'],
        justification: 'testing' // details for using the API
    });
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    let audio_url = ""
    playSound(audio_url);
});

async function playSound(source) {
    await createOffscreen();
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ play: { source } });
}
```

`offscreen.html` is just read offscreen.js

```
<script src="offscreen.js"></script>
```

`offscreen.js` recieve messagen and play audio.

```
// Listen for messages from the extension
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if ('play' in msg) {
        playAudio(msg.play);
        sendResponse(true);
    }
    return true;
});
let audio = null;

# source is audio url or audio file path.
function playAudio({ source }) {
    audio = new Audio(source);
    audio.play();
}
```

I hope this information is helpful to you.